# iOS chat APNS, sockets or time interval

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, chat, apple-push-notifications

I'm making a chat app for iPhone, but im not sure how conversation messages should come instantly.

I have read tons of Google results on this topic. Also the once on:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

**APNS approach:** 

An invisible notification will be pushed to the iPhone indicating that a new message is ready to be read. So the app will make a request for unread messages. So instead of manually polling new messages, I will let APNS help with that. But I'm not sure?

**Sockets approach:** 

Making a socket connection that is open to share data. When new messages is found in db, it will automatic send the data to the app. But what about IP range, firewall, power consumption, other things? again I'm not sure :(

**Polling approach:**

Make a time interval where I poll request, power consumption is my enemy here.

**My question:** 

- Which approach is best? 

- Other suggestions? 

- I really need some cons and pros from people with experience on this topic.

Examples is always good.

Thanks

Comment: Polling gives you reliability, better delay and timeout control, and as a plus, you'll be free to choose how to present your data. With Push Notifications, you have no guarantees that your message was successfully delivered. Apple does not guarantee it. Therefore I would not rely on Apple to deliver chat messages to my users.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. APNS shouldn't send the chat messages themself, it should only... "poke"/"invoke" the app that some new unread messages is ready to be read.

Comment: What you are not sure about the APNS method? Push Notifications don't require background execution, which is a big win because an application in the suspended state saves battery.

Comment: Other suggestions? I really need some cons and pros from people with experience on this topic

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is if your user denies push notifications, your messenger is out of luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your main concern is how to receive new messages while your application is in the background. Because it's not like I'm going to have a messenger app all day open when I can get notifications with apps like WhatsApp.

Better than TCPIP sockets you could use [websockets](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/). Since it is HTTP there are no firewall problems, BUT that requires a permanent connection with application on the foreground which drains the battery.

And because only music, location, or voice ip, is allowed to run on the background, you can't poll unless the application is open. Note that if you register for those background tasks and do something else Apple will notice and reject your app.

Therefore, use APNS. That's what WhatsApp does.

Comment: Good points. Even if I stick with APNS, I still believe the future is in somehow .. persistent connections (sockets or other things) - where you don't have to refresh manually. Thanks for the example of WhatsApp.

Comment: I'm only really concerned about the foreground part. Do I take by your answer that WhatsApp relies solely on push notifications to know it has to pull new messages, even when it's the app running in the foreground?

Answer (score 2):

Use XMPP SERVER for chat purpose

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/

I hope this link will be useful to you.